# How to search for elements with class starts with particular character and replace them with new class name in extjs

Tags: extjs

For example,

```
<div class="level1">
</div>
```

I need to search for elements with class name starting with level and programatically replace them as "level2".
How can this be done in extjs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Comment: May I know if the answer helped you? You know, on this site you're expected to give some feedback or accept the answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how. Look at the docs for the various functions to learn how to adapt.

```
var targets = Ext.query('.level1');

Ext.each(targets, function(domEl) {
    Ext.fly(domEl) // get a reference to Ext.Element from the raw ROM element
       .removeCls('level1')
       .addCls('level2');
});
```